# Energy of cubic dipole lattice

Tags: electrostatics, energy, crystals, dipole

Consider a single dipole in a cubic box with periodic boundary conditions, or an infinite cubic lattice/grid of parallel dipoles. Is there a simple expression for the energy?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Interesting question.  How simple of an expression do you want?  One can probably write it as an infinite sum the same way you do for the [Madelung constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant), and one can probably find a numerical value for it.  Thankfully, the rapid fall-off of the fields means that you won't have to deal with conditional convergence.  But I do suspect (given the example of the Madelung constant in 3D) that there might not be a closed-form expression.

Comment: On second thought, the sum is going to be conditionally convergent, since while interaction energy is proportional to $1/r^3$, the number of dipoles within a distance $r$ will be proportional to $r^2$.

Comment: Also, can we assume that $\vec{p}$ is parallel to one of the lattice vectors?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert A solution for the case with the dipoles parallel to a lattice vector would be great. If there is a solution for any direction that would be even greater, but I suspect that this could be a difficult problem. I didn't specify it, hoping for the best!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If there exists no simple formula (say $E = p/l^2$ for $p$ along a lattice vector of length $l$) I suspect some fourier-transforms could do it, similar to the Ewald-sum, which would be fine also.